# HTTP status code for token in the Authorization header that doesn't belong to the user

Tags: java, http, authorization, http-status-codes

Can you recommend which HTTP status code is suitable to be returned when a user tries to use another users token? `401` or `400` ?

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP** **403** **Forbidden** *The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.* is better for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

403 would be the most appropriate response code.  Here's the complete description from [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1).

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood
> the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to
> make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that
> reason in the response payload (if any).

> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the
> server considers them insufficient to grant access.  The client
> SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same
> credentials.  The client MAY repeat the request with new or different
> credentials.  However, a request might be forbidden for reasons
> unrelated to the credentials.

> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a
> forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of
> 404 (Not Found).

The 2nd paragraph applies to your scenario.  The client / user has supplied someone else's  credentials, and server considers them "insufficient".

Comment: From the consent(retrieved with the use of token) it gets TPP ref and compares  with connected TPP ref